# Aspose.Barcode - Attempted to read past the end of the stream exception in Dynamics 365 plugin

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, aspose.barcode

I am trying to write a Dynamics 365 plugin using Aspose.Barcode, however, every time I try to set the license or extract a barcode the library throws a System.IO.EndOfStreamException "Attempted to read past the end of the stream" exception.

For example I have the following lines of code in the application to set the licence:

```
string license = GetAsposeLicense();
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(license);
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    License barCodeLicense = new License();
    barCodeLicense.SetLicense(stream);
}
```

The funny thing is the same lines of code work perfectly fine when used in a Console application; both written in dotnet Framework 4.5.2. I am using ILMerge to merge all the assemblies into one Dynamics 365 plugin library.

I guess my questions are:

1. Do Dynamics 365 plugins have issues working with streams?
2. Could it be an issue with ILMerge?
3. Is there a potential workaround?

Comment: When `string license = GetAsposeLicense();` has been executed, is `license` set to a valid license string? You could write its value to the plugin trace log.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can be
2. Can be
3. Move the logic to Azure (like an Azure Function or similar) or find another library

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I am thinking the same and just reaching out to Aspose to check if I can do that given my current licence. 

If they confirm I can use the library in an Azure function then I will mark your answer as the solution. 

Thanks again.

Comment: Sadly Aspose have confirmed that if their product is used within an API/Azure function for both external and internal uses then you require the high end licenses.